# How to predefine an array of vectors in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to pre-define the variable subsample, below, in such a way that the code works.  I have been attempting different definition syntaxs for hours. I need minimal code changes, so I can directly compute means from the vectors as shown in the bottom of the code.

The second code block works and shows the desired effect. I need to use for loops, because I need to do this with much larger sets of subsamples.

```
> scores=rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 1000, sd = 200)
> sample_a = sample(x=scores, size = 1000, replace=FALSE)
    
> subsample= ????-need definition-????
>for(i in 1:10) {
    a=(i-1)*100+1
    b=i*100
    subsample[i]=sample_a[a:b]  
    }
```

This is an attempt to reduce the 2nd paragraph of code, below, to a for loop.

```
> scores=rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 1000, sd = 200)
> sample_a = sample(x=scores, size = 1000, replace=FALSE)

> sample_a1=sample_a[1:100]
> sample_a2=sample_a[101:200]
> sample_a3=sample_a[201:300]
> sample_a4=sample_a[301:400]
> sample_a5=sample_a[401:500]
> sample_a6=sample_a[501:600]
> sample_a7=sample_a[601:700]
> sample_a8=sample_a[701:800]
> sample_a9=sample_a[801:900]
> sample_a10=sample_a[901:1000]

> y=c()
> y[1]=mean(sample_a1)
> y[2]=mean(sample_a2)
> y[3]=mean(sample_a3)
> y[4]=mean(sample_a4)
> y[5]=mean(sample_a5)
> y[6]=mean(sample_a6)
> y[7]=mean(sample_a7)
> y[8]=mean(sample_a8)
> y[9]=mean(sample_a9)
> y[10]=mean(sample_a10)
> mean(y)
[1] 1004.78
> sd(y)
[1] 30.282
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, we can create a `group` and then do a group by operation for `mean`

```
tapply(sample_a, as.integer(gl(length(sample_a), 100, length(sample_a))),
           FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and `sd`

```
tapply(sample_a, as.integer(gl(length(sample_a), 100, length(sample_a))), 
        FUN = sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(col1 = sample_a) %>%
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 100, n()))) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(col1, na.rm = TRUE), SD = sd(col1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

If we need a `for` loop to create objects in the global environment (not recommended though)

```
v1 <- seq(1, 1000, by = 100)
for(i in seq_along(v1)) {
      assign(paste0("sample_a", i), sample_a[v1[i]:(v1[i] + 99)])
  }
```

Or using `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(v1, function(x) sample_a[x:(x + 99)])
names(lst1) <- paste0("sample_a", seq_along(lst1))
```

With the `list`, it is easier to apply functions

```
sapply(lst1, mean)
sapply(lst1, sd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need to know how to pre-define an array of vectors.   I see examples of joining existing vectors into an array, but they are not pre-existing here.  I am changing existing C code into R, and your methodology would entail a COMPLETE rewrite of all the pre-existing algorithmic logic.  Also, I don't think you re-write could be integrated into other parts of the existing system.

Comment: People now see this has an answer, but - "I need to pre-define the variable subsample, below, in such a way that the code works"  and "I need minimal code changes"

Comment: @Jason_93. So, you need to create the vectors right?

Comment: @Jason_93 Do you need a `for` loop as answer?

Comment: Yes and Yes.  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just predefine an array of vectors?  Being able to do this would make my life so much simpler.  I appreciate your updated answer, but it's another re-write.

Comment: @Jason_93 It is not clear.  You said you wanted a `for` loop

Comment: @Jason_93 creating a `list` seems reasonable to me.  Updated the post

Comment: Sorry, but I am only interested in answers where the variable "subsample" is defined as an ARRAY of VECTORS, and the code is otherwise left alone (except for how to address it, "subsample[i,?]"   Thanks.

Comment: @Jason_93 sorry, you comment is not clear to me.  My code is based on your code blocks in your post

Comment: "subsample[i]=sample_a[a:b] "  -- How do I predefine "subsample" so I can assign vectors to it like that?  ---  I can predefine "y" so I can later assign values to it: " y=c()" and y[1]=mean(sample_a1)"

Comment: @Jason_93 what is the issue in the `for` loop or `lapply` which does the same thing

Comment: The question is how to create an array of vectors.  That is what I need.

Comment: @Jason_93. what you meant by `array` is `array(1:64, dim = c(4, 4, 4))`.  Anyway, I am out.  You may downvote if you want.  Thanks

Comment: That creates a 4x4 array filled with the numbers from 1 to 64. ---  I will wait for somebody else to reply.

Comment: @Jason_93 what you meant by `array` and `array` in `R` are different.  Thanks

Comment: This fails with an error: x = array(data=NA, dim = c(10, 100)) ;;
x[1] = sample_a[1:10] ;;
Warning message:
In x[1] = sample_a[1:10] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @Jason_93 your question in the post `he second code block works and shows the desired effect. I need to use for loops, because I need to do this with much larger sets of subsamples.`. I showed with a `for` loop. thanks

Comment: The answer was simple.  I've added it.  Thanks for your help - even though it isn't what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. It's simple. You have to explicitly state the size/cells (",1:100").  The error message I was getting didn't say that.

```
subsample_a=array(data=NA, dim = c(10, 100))
for(i in 1:10) {
  +   a=(i-1)*100+1
  +   b=i*100
  +   subsample_a[i,1:100]=sample_a[a:b]  
  + }
```